# return serial Comunication with async void

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I have an async event handler in my code to receive and send strings via serial UART.
In the example here, I do only receive. 
Is there a way to use the string rxBuffer outside of Serial() ?
I have to use the value on a different page.

I read that async void cannot return a value.
async Task would be the right way. How to change the code to make it happen?
My tries allways fail.

```
    using System;
    using Windows.System;                       //ShutdownManager
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;          //UART Serial
    using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;  //UART Serial
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;              //Uart Serial

    //Main
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Serial();
    } //Main


    //Serial
    public async void Serial()
    {
        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");                   /* Find the selector string for the serial device   */
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);                    /* Find the serial device with our selector string  */
        SerialDevice SerialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);    /* Create an serial device with our selected device */

        /* Configure serial settings */
        SerialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        SerialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;                                             /* mini UART: only standard baudrates */
        SerialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;                                  /* mini UART: no parities */
        SerialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;                           /* mini UART: 1 stop bit */
        SerialPort.DataBits = 8;

        DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
        const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
        DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);

        while (true)
        {
            //Receive
            uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);
            string rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
            textblock_DebugRx_live.Text = rxBuffer;    
        }
    } //Serial
```

I tried it with Task as well.
As you can see I'm not really a pro.

What am I missing?
With this code my textblock_DebugRx_live displays:

> System.Threading.TasksTask`1[System.String]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;   //nötig für await Task
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;     //GPIO for Raspberry
using Windows.System;           //ShutdownManager
using Windows.UI;               //Schriftfarbe ändern
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;    //Schriftfarbe ändern
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;          //UART Seriell
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;  //UART Seriell
using Windows.Storage.Streams;              //Uart Seriell

namespace TAR_Win_IoT
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

    //Main
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Serial();
        var b = Serial();
        string c = b.ToString();
        textblock_Rx_live.Text = c;
    } //Main


    //Seriell
    public async Task<string> Serial()
    {
        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");                   /* Find the selector string for the serial device   */
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);                    /* Find the serial device with our selector string  */
        SerialDevice SerialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);    /* Create an serial device with our selected device */

        /* Configure serial settings */
        SerialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        SerialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;                                             /* mini UART: only standard baudrates */
        SerialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;                                  /* mini UART: no parities */
        SerialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;                           /* mini UART: 1 stop bit */
        SerialPort.DataBits = 8;

        DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
        const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
        DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);

        while (true)
        {
            //Receive
            uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);

            string rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
            textblock_DebugRx_live.Text = rxBuffer;
            return rxBuffer;
        }
       } //Seriell
      }//Main
     }//ENDE
```

Comment: _"My tries allways fail"_ -- show us the code that is closest to what you want, but which fails. More generally: not only can `void` not return a value, but you should avoid `async void` completely, except for specific event handler scenarios. You can use `async Task<string>` to return a `string`, for example. But you need to then `await` the task that's returned, to get the string out. Please do some research, study the `async`/`await` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You should await `Serial()`, for example in an async `Loaded` event handler:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= OnLoaded;
    string b = await Serial();
    textblock_Rx_live.Text = b;
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured out how to send strings to a different page. So I don't need to get it out of the async task<>, I can just keep my async void.

Comment: @TonicLoyal: Great but please remember to accept the answer.